# Spring GuavaCacheManager CacheBuilder RemovalListener ClassCastException possibility

Tags: java, spring, caching, guava, spring-cache

I have been using Spring GuavaCacheManager for caching in my application.

Spring version 4.3, Guava version 20.0

I'm initialising guava cache builder in spring configuration file and using cacheable annotation in cache file.

As per Guava CacheBuilder RemovalListener docs,

> Warning: after invoking this method, do not continue to use this cache
>   builder reference; instead use the reference this method returns. At
>   runtime, these point to the same instance, but only the returned
>   reference has the correct generic type information so as to ensure
>   type safety. For best results, use the standard method-chaining idiom
>   illustrated in the class documentation above, configuring a builder
>   and building your cache in a single statement. Failure to heed this
>   advice can result in a ClassCastException being thrown by a cache
>   operation at some undefined point in the future.

*I'm using the reference returned by removal listener in spring configuration file but still is there any possibility of ClassCastException being thrown by a cache operation at some undefined point in the future for the below code?*

**Spring configuration file**

```
@configuration
@EnableCaching
public class SpringConfig {

@Bean
public CacheBuilder<Object, Object> cacheBuilder() {
    CacheBuilder<Object, Object> cacheBuilder = CacheBuilder.from("maximumSize=1000,expireAfterAccess=1d").removalListener(addRemovalListener());

    return cacheBuilder;
}

@Autowired
private CacheBuilder<Object, Object> cacheBuilder;

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    GuavaCacheManager cacheManager = new GuavaCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCacheBuilder(cacheBuilder);
    cacheManager.setAllowNullValues(false);
    return cacheManager;
}

private RemovalListener<Object, Object> addRemovalListener() {
    return new RemovalListener<Object, Object>() {
        public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification<Object, Object> removal) {

            if(RemovalCause.EXPLICIT != removal.getCause()) {

                try {
                    String key = (String) removal.getKey();
                    String val = (String) removal.getValue();
                    ......
                    ......
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Cache RemovalListener Exception [{}]", e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

}
```

**Spring Cache File**

```
@Service
public class SpringCache {

@Autowired
private CacheManager cacheManager;

@Cacheable(cacheManager="cacheManager", key="#p0", cacheNames="cacheKeysMap", sync=true)
public String getKeyFromCache(String key) {
    ......
    ......
    return value;
}

@CacheEvict(cacheManager="cacheManager", key="#p0", cacheNames="cacheKeysMap")
public void deleteFromCache(String key) {

}

}
```